# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: magento

I've used the SQL scripts at this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/import-export_and_data_manipulation/removing_products_through_the_database)  to remove all test product data and categories. I've then read the category 'Products' and then imported my CSV file, which Magento says is fine when checking the data, but when I click import I am receiving the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`gare6221_qshed/catalog_product_website`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_CAT_PRD_WS_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`)
>   REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE )

Any ideas guys? I'm really struggling with this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed and the problem was due to SKU lengths being above 64 characters.

Comment: Worked with me except that I had a product with empty SKU.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would say is to avoid doing things directly with the database. It can get messy really quick (as you are learning).

Having said that, it looks like you may have some leftover data somewhere. Perhaps catalog_product_website?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. It turns out it was to do with some of the SKU's in the CSV being over 64 characters long.

After a restore of a full cPanel backup I left the old data in and tried to import and got the same error. When I reduced the mentioned SKU's it worked. So something to bare in mind in future.

Comment: Wow. Never would have expected that one. Good thing to share with everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing this issue as well, though SKU's don't seem to be the cause (our SKUS are in the format of 'FOO-####'), so none of them are anywhere near 64 characters.

When I select the csv file and select check data, it passes the check fine:

```
Checked rows: 1718, checked entities: 47, invalid rows: 0, total errors: 0
File is valid! To start import process press "Import" button
```

After selecting import, however, I receive this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magentoss`.`catalog_product_option_type_value`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_OPT_TYPE_VAL_OPT_ID_CAT_PRD_OPT_OPT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`option_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_option` (`option_id`) ON D), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_option_type_value` (`option_type_id`,`sort_order`,`sku`,`option_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

After checking the product listings, it does seem as though the file was uploaded, as all my data was updated, so not entirely sure what's going on.